# C# Thread Delegate Question

Tags: c#, datagrid, delegates, multithreading

I am in a position that I finally am forced to split a program of mine into threads, as it is painfully slow. 

My situation is that I have two ComponentOne Flexgrid DataGridView components... One allows direct editing. And I need the second grid to update its contents based off of the first grid.

Currently what I have is along these lines:

```
class MyApp
{
    void GridOne_AfterEdit(object sender, RowColEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateList();
    }

    void UpdateList()
    {
        foreach (Row r in GridOne.Rows)
        {
            //calculate information per row and add to GridTwo
        }
    }
}
```

And this is unbearably slow... From what I understand with delegates I need to have a delegate for each component I need to access/reference?

I have tried things such as assigning GridTwo to a DataTable and modifying the DataTable from the thread, but only end up with blank entrys.
Also, I've noticed I have issues restarting it, I suppose I could have the thread  always listening or responding to a Boolean value.

Not asking for someone to complete my code. Simply asking what an efficient choice would be for this. Thanks for any tips!

Comment: I would first suggest you look at a memory profiler to see exactly were your application is taking its time and which methods are taking the most time. Then refactor and see if you can speed it up that way.

Comment: Please add you code for //calculate information per row and add to GridTwo, maybe I can see something thats causing it to run slow.

Comment: Is it the enumeration of the rows that is slow or the calculations? If it is the former then this just got really hard. If it is the later then we can probably help. Remember, touching any UI element from another thread (even if it is just a `Row`) is a big no-no.

Comment: It is the calculations that are slow. Its a refining calculator for the industrial side of Eve Online. For each row in GridOne, is an Ore. Each ore yeilds 1-4 minerals, that get totaled up and the ammounts are calculated based on equipment and skills.
so its quite a lot of calculations, which if i could find how to move the entire portion to another thread would speed it up. 

Would it be smarter to work mainly with DataTables and edit/read the contents from the DataTables as opposed to direct interaction with the component? Or could I set up a kindof listener thread, and have the thread loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (Row r in GridOne.Rows)
```

Isn't going to be threaded with any kind of fun or success.

Comment: Hmmm...it depends on your definition of "fun" now doesn't it :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you might do to get parallelism is segment your rowset, something like (no intellisense here so please forgive minor misuses):

```
var gridOneFirstHalf = new Row[][] { GridOne.Rows.Take(GridOne.Rows.Count / 2), new Row[GridOne.Rows.Count / 2] };
var gridOneSecondHalf = new Row[][] { GridOne.Rows.Skip(GridOne.Rows.Count / 2).ToArray(), new Row[GridOne.Rows.Count / 2] };

ParameterizedThreadStart halfThreadStarter = new ParameterizedThreadState((state) => ProcessIntoResultsMember(state));

Thread processFirstHalf = new Thread(halfThreadStarter, gridOneFirstHalf);
Thread processSecondHalf = new Thread(halfThreadStarter, gridOneSecondHalf);

processFirstHalf.Start();
processSecondHalf.Start();

processFirstHalf.Join();
processSecondHalf.Join();

GridTwo.Rows = gridOneFirstHalf[1].Concat(gridOneSecondHalf[1]);
```

I'm not familiar with this GridOne control or whether the linq extensions I was referring to are available..

Comment: Ah, but how do we know that `Row` instances are exempt from the normal thread affinity requirements like most other UI elements and their constituent data structures?

Comment: @Brian one should always verify thread safety with an objects documentation, but in the example, one would only be doing reads on the live assigned rows for the purpose of constructing the new rows. one would need to lock all ui or others from write operations on the rows through other means

Comment: Well, yeah, what I am saying is that most UI elements are *affinitized* to the UI thread. So you cannot do anything to them, even just reads, from another thread; at least you're not *suppose* to. No amount of locking will fix that.

Comment: Well then, How forms such as Visual studio, with multiple panels and views. interact with eachother?

Comment: Preparing the data to be readable in a thread safe manner may mean getting the data out of the rows first or anything else necessary to ensure thread safety, i'm merely proposing a parallelism strategy.

Comment: I could easily dump the Rows into a RowCollection and most likly set the Rows of GridTwo to the returned RowCollection.

I guess I would use a delegate to retrieve, and another to set the RowCollection. Anyone mind telling me if I'm on the right track with that? haha.

Comment: @Pcstalljr: I would take Jimmy's answer here as a starting point. Really, the only thing different I would do is to copy all of the necessary data from the rows in `GridOne` into completely separate data structures first before shuttling them off to a worker thread. Reverse the procedure to build the new rows for `GridTwo`. Whatever you do make sure that you do not touch a ComponentOne `Row` from anything other than the main UI thread. Don't attempt to read one, create one, or even think about it in your sleep.

Comment: Interesting you would say that @Brian Gideon. the method I am currently using is very very fast. I am copying the Rows from GridOne then directly editing values on GridTwo according to the calculations. since GridTwo does not accept any input. Also, I'm not sure why you say not to touch a ComponentOne Row, As I am having no issues building the table programmatically with custom textbox components embedded, extra masks, etc. and it seems to be running quite nicely.

Comment: @Pcstalljr: I actually said "do not touch a ComponentOne `Row` from **anything other than the main UI thread**".